# Find nested variable inside json payload

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm using the find function in postman tests to save environment variables,
the find function works great when I'm looking for a variable, But I cannot get it to work when looking for variables inside an object

My payload looks something like this

```
{
    "name": "product1",
    "state": {
        "DefinitionId": "productcard",
        "Id": "32919b8c-984e-46c3-933d-51d3c621d4cf"
    },
    "status": "Done"
},
{
    "name": "product2",
    "state": {
        "DefinitionId": "productaccount",
        "Id": "4999b8c-984e-46c3-933d-55d3c621d4cf"
    },
    "status": "NotDone"
},
```

with the _find function I can find variables through the name variable

```
 var steps = _.find(resBody, { 
        name: "product1", 
    })
    pm.environment.set(steps.name, steps.state.Id);
```

But what If I want to search by DefinitionId?
I have tried stuffs like this

```
 _.find(resBody, { 
      name.state: "product1", 
      }) <--did not work

 _.find(resBody.state, { 
      name.state: "product1", 
      }) <--did not work [returns object object]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should return the an object by a DefinitionId search, if that's what you mean?

`var result = resBody.find(x => x.state.DefinitionId === "productaccount");`